# Drop unnamed referential integrity constraint in Teradata

Tags: sql, constraints, teradata, referential-integrity

Is it possible to drop an unnamed referential integrity constraint in Teradata?
Example:

**Parent table:**

```
CREATE SET TABLE MIGRATION_TOOL.UNIT_TEST_EXISTING_TABLE_DEPENDENCY_PARENT,
    NO FALLBACK,
    NO BEFORE JOURNAL,
    NO AFTER JOURNAL,
    CHECKSUM = DEFAULT,
    DEFAULT MERGEBLOCKRATIO (
        ID INTEGER,
        NAME VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC NOT NULL,
        DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC NOT NULL,
        CREATION_DATE TIMESTAMP(6) DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
        LAST_UPDATE TIMESTAMP(6) DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)
    )
UNIQUE PRIMARY INDEX UPI ( ID );
```

**Child Table:**

```
CREATE SET TABLE MIGRATION_TOOL.UNIT_TEST_EXISTING_TABLE_DEPENDENCY_CHILD,
    NO FALLBACK,
    NO BEFORE JOURNAL,
    NO AFTER JOURNAL,
    CHECKSUM = DEFAULT,
    DEFAULT MERGEBLOCKRATIO (
        ID INTEGER,
        NAME VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC NOT NULL,
        DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC NOT NULL,
        CREATION_DATE TIMESTAMP(6) DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
        LAST_UPDATE TIMESTAMP(6) DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
        PARENT_ID INTEGER,
        FOREIGN KEY ( PARENT_ID ) REFERENCES WITH NO CHECK OPTION MIGRATION_TOOL.UNIT_TEST_EXISTING_TABLE_DEPENDENCY_PARENT ( ID )
    )
UNIQUE PRIMARY INDEX UPI ( ID );
```

How to drop the Foreign Key / Soft Referential Integrity Rule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found it...

```
ALTER TABLE MIGRATION_TOOL.UNIT_TEST_EXISTING_TABLE_DEPENDENCY_CHILD
DROP FOREIGN KEY (PARENT_ID) REFERENCES 
MIGRATION_TOOL.UNIT_TEST_EXISTING_TABLE_DEPENDENCY_PARENT(ID);
```